# performance - multithreaded or multiprocess applications

Tags: linux, multithreading, multiprocessing

In order to develop a highly network intensive server application on linux, what sort of architecture is preferred? The idea is that this app would typically run on machines with multiple cores (either virtual or physical). Considering that performance is the key criteria, is it better to go for a multi-threaded application or the one with multi-process design? I do know that sharing of resources and synchronization to access of such resources from multiple processes is a lot of programming overhead, but as mentioned earlier overall performance is the key requirement and so we can ignore those things. And the programming language would be C/C++.

I have heard that even the multi-threaded applications (single process) can take advantage of multiple cores and run each thread on a different core independently (as long as there is no sync issues). And this scheduling is done by the kernel. If so, is there not much difference in performance between multi-threaded applications and multi-process applications? Nginx uses a multi-process architecture and is really quick, but can one get the same performance with multi-threaded applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes and threads on linux are very similar to each other - the main difference is that the whole virtual memory is shared as well as certain things like signal handling differ.

This makes for cheaper context switches between threads (no need for costly MMU reloads etc.) but doesn't necessarily cause much difference in speed (especially outside of thread creation).

For designing a highly network intensive application, basically the **only** solution is to use an evented architecture (otherwise you'll bog down the system with huge amount of processes/threads and spend more time on their management than actually running work code), where you react to I/O on sockets and based on which sockets exhibit activity do apropriate operations.

A famous writeup about the problems faced in such situations is *"The C10k problem"*, available from http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html - it describes different I/O approaches, so despite being a bit dated, it's a very good introduction.

Be careful before jumping deeply into reactor-like designs, though - they can get unwieldy and complex, so see if you can't use library/language that provides a nicer abstraction over it (Erlang is my personal favourite in this, languages with coroutines like Go can be useful too).

Comment: @p-l: Thanks for your answer. Yes, the plan is to use even-based architecture and act based on the network events. And no additional threads and processes are created during runtime. Given this, do you see no performance difference between multi-threaded and multi-process applications? For eg: if there is a system with say 4 cores, there will not be any noticeable different in performance between both architectures?

Comment: The biggest possible differences would be in scheduling, and that can be modified with cpu affinity of the task, pinning each task (thread/process) to specific cpu. More differences could be from actual work done by server process and how it interacts with network part.

There can be differences related to how memory is accessed, but less related to thread/process difference as to sharing memory in general on a NUMA system - though it's possible that the current kernels have support to make copies of code segments in different NUMA zones (they did have that for kernel itself in the past).

Answer (score 2):

If your threads are doing the job independent from one another, under linux, there is simply no reason to not going with multiple processes instead. Multiple processes would increase your memory usage as each process has its own private memory space, but on the other hand sharing the memory space between independent threads is the worse decision. Context switching between threads vs processes is usually done better for processes rather than threads although its a little bit architecture and code dependent. Processes are safe to not get serialized with locks and mutex es. Processes are easier to manage and interact with in Linux. here is a good document you might find interesting (http://elinux.org/images/1/1c/Ben-Yossef-GoodBadUgly.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the document, very helpful.  I believe that the perception that threads are much faster comes from the early Windows environments which would create complete processes from scratch, unlike Linux fork which merely duplicates the stack and initially both child and parent process share the same memory segments.  I think that code, unless an exec call is made, continues to be shared amongst all child processes and the parent.

Comment: The brief description and link to document is very much helpful.