# Is pthreads more efficient/effective than CLI for multithreading on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, fork

I've read that multiprocessing is often favored over multithreading on Unix based systems, and that this is due to Unix based systems being more efficient handling many processes as opposed to many threads (or that it is simply easier to manage many processes than many threads).

I've also read that Windows users prefer multithreading because Windows is less efficient with multiprocessing.

So if I'm on a Linux based server and need to pick between multiprocessing or multithreading, what is my best bet to maximize efficiency and effectiveness?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Fakhruddin, good call :)

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Where did you read 'multiprocessing is often favored over multithreading'?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the mulitprocessing over multithreading information is old (like pre-2.6 Linux when multithreading wasn't particularly implemented well on Linux, for example, LinuxThreads vs. NGPT vs. NPTL)

Comment: @MartinJames I found a similar question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580244/performance-multithreaded-or-multiprocess-applications) alluding to the idea that it "doesn't make a big difference" performance wise on Linux.  The notion that multiprocessing is often a preference is from other reading I've done over the past week or so, for which I don't have a specific reference at hand right now.